# Flowplayer error message

Tags: 6, files

I'm using the [video](http://drupal.org/project/video) module in combination with the [Flowplayer](http://drupal.org/project/flowplayer) module to allow my users to upload Flash videos. This works fine if autoplay is enabled, however if it isn't, I get the following error message:

> 200, Stream not found, NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound, clip: '[Clip] 'http://www.mydrupalsite.com/sites/default/files/''

Am I doing something wrong?